# Set value of numberfield without firing "change" event in Sencha Touch

Tags: events, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have a numberfield and a list in Sencha Touch.  When I click on an item in the list, I am doing an AJAX request to send data to the server.  However, if there is data in the numberfield, I want to clear that when the list is clicked on.

I have no problem doing this (I am setting the value to a blank string), however, the change event is fired on the numberfield.  This causes another AJAX request to run which doesn't need to.  Is there any way to clear a numberfield WITHOUT firing the change event?  SuspendEvents does not work as clearing the numberfield requires an event.

Any thoughts or suggestions?  Thanks!

Code lines that I have tried:

`suspendEvents();` `me.getWhatScreen().down('numberfield[name=caseNumber]').setValue('');` `resumeEvents(true);`

`me.suspendEvents();` `me.getWhatScreen().down('numberfield[name=caseNumber]').setValue('');` `me.resumeEvents(true);`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Do `suspendEvents()`, update your numberfield and then do `resumeEvents()`

**UPDATE**

```
var control = me.getWhatScreen().down(...);
control.suspendEvents();
control.setValue('');
control.resumeEvents(false);
```

Comment: Thanks for responding.  I tried your suggestions.  When I call `me.suspendEvents()`, update the numberfield code, and then call `me.resumeEvents(true or false)`, the numberfield is cleared, but both AJAX requests are run.  If I just do `suspendEvents()`, update the numberfield code, and then `resumeEvents(true or false)` the code to set the value of the numberfield does not work.  Only the one AJAX request is made, but the numberfield is not cleared.  Any other thoughts?

Comment: I think you need to suspend/resume event on the control level not on the global level.

Comment: I am currently running this code in a function in my controller.  Do you mean use `this.suspend/resumeEvents`?  I have done code `var me = this` at the top of my function in my controller.  Any clarification?

Comment: Having the same problem, my Model needs to "fill" 7 inputs, and change triggers them "onChange". Why is there no "Tap or Select" Sencha...?

Comment: The `false` parameter at `control.resumeEvents(false)` has no effect, because resumeEvents takes no argument. The poster intended to not queue the events, but that's to be decided upon calling suspendEvents where the default for the argument queueSuspended is false. It's all here: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.util.Observable-method-suspendEvents

Comment: When this question was asked and answered `resumeEvents` had a parameter and `suspendEvents` didn't. It definitely was prior to 4.2.1 release.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE for Sencha Touch 2.4**

the correct sequence is

```
var control = me.getWhatScreen().down(...);
control.suspendEvents();
control.setValue('');
control.resumeEvents(true);
```

[resumeEvents](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.4/2.4.2-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.mixin.Observable-method-resumeEvents) takes the boolean parameter **discardQueuedEvents**